# What are the advantages between using AWS CLI and AWS PHP SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-php-sdk

I want to sync some folders on S3 bucket. I can do it with AWS CLI or use PHP SDK but I want to know what are the advantages and disadvantages between two methods? Any performance differences?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI has the quite powerful `aws s3 sync` command that syncs local directories and S3 buckets nicely. On the other hand, setting specific headers/metadata could be easier when doing it programmatically through the API.